# Unity 5 - 2D game - separate scenes vs panels

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try read all post like
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/scenes-vs-canvases-vs-panels.279890/
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/with-new-ui-separate-scenes-or-just-separate-panels.281013/
and others and still don't understand what is better way?

Scenes vs panels.

I'm personally thing scenes is better - I feel separate levels.

A game i try to write familiar to candy crush and how i understand they use scenes - because from map to play new matches gam you see loading screen - i thing this is some scene.

Thank you

Comment: use scenes.  Canvas is only for your "UI" (buttons like "Play!" "Quit!" etc)

Comment: @JoeBlow Yes you are right. Canvas is for UI. I think that games like Candy Crush is one of the few exceptions where you can and if possible use the UI. The game does not require Physics. All it does is display image/text and you click on them to switch them around...Although I don't think this is the right place to post this question.

Comment: You know, it's probably true that u or I could do a candy game in the .UI !  I think the idea is not useful pedagogically though: the OP simply doesn't realize that is "not what UI is for", you know (OP is muddled, I'd say ...)

Comment: @JoeBlow I agree. He is likely a beginner and is confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> because from map to play new matches gam you see loading screen

Because you see a loading screen does not mean that the game is actually laoding a scene. Anyone can put a loading screen up while doing something else such as loading `AssetBundles` and not actually loading the scene.

Your question will only result to opinion answer since you don't really have any problem.

I have my own rules I use after experimenting with Unity.

If you are making a 3D game with color map, normal map, height map and other textures, use Scene. Separate the scenes to speed up loading each level.

Now, if you are making a 2D Game as simple as candy Crush that uses few `Sprites` and `Images` simply use Canvas/Panels. Make **Level 1** as parent `Canvas` GameObject. For **level 2**, simply duplicate the **Level 1** parent `Canvas`, rename it to **Level 2** then make a little changes to it. You can switch levels by **enabling** and **disabling**  the parent `Canvas` GameObjects.

This make modifying your 2D Game very easy.You can easily compare what two levels look like by enabling/disabling them. You don't have to load up another scene to get another level. Also loading scene takes time too but this eliminates that.

Another advantage of this is that you can always convert the Canvas parent of each level into a prefab then import it into another level if you want to start using scenes instead.

Comment: Only 1 more question - Level 1 and Level 2 - you mean - Level 1 its map - level 2 - its play view, Right?

Comment: @David For example, in this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/13mHW.png, You setup your UI like that but named them Level1Canvas, Level2Cavas, Level3Canvas, Level4Canvas. Only 1 level can be enabled at a time. To enable another level simple disable the current one with `Level1Canvas.SetActive(false);` then enable the next Level with  `Level2Canvas.SetActive(true);`. This is easy and probably the right way since Candy Crush like games uses few sprites. All your images should be put under each level Canvas GameObject. For example, put all level one stuff inside/under Level1Canvas.

Comment: Thank you  again )